Why do these two identical JPQL queries in Hibernate return different result counts?
I am learning about the internals of Hibernate, which is an implementation of JPA, and I encountered a behavior I don't fully understand. I have following two JPQL queries:
String jpqlWithObjectType = """
                    SELECT l\s
                    FROM Library l
                    JOIN Member m
                    ON m.library.id = l.id\s
                    """;
            TypedQuery<Object[]> query1 = entityManager.createQuery(jpqlWithObjectType, Object[].class);
            List<Object[]> libraries = query1.getResultList();
            System.out.println(libraries.size());

            String jpqlWithLibraryType = """
                    SELECT l\s
                    FROM Library l
                    JOIN Member m
                    ON m.library.id = l.id\s
                    """;
            TypedQuery<Library> query2 = entityManager.createQuery(jpqlWithLibraryType, Library.class);
            List<Library> libraries3 = query2.getResultList();
            System.out.println(libraries3.size());

Now consider there are 3 libraries and 5 members and there is a one to many relationship between Library and Member.
INSERT INTO Library (id, name, location, establishedDate) VALUES
(1, 'Central Library', 'Downtown', '1990-03-15'),
(2, 'West End Library', 'West City', '1985-07-20'),
(3, 'East Side Library', 'East City', '2000-09-05');

INSERT INTO Member (id, first_name, last_name, email, location, library_id) VALUES
(1, 'Alice', 'Johnson', 'alice.johnson@example.com', 'Downtown', 1),
(2, 'Bob', 'Smith', 'bob.smith@example.com', 'West City', 2),
(3, 'Charlie', 'Brown', 'charlie.brown@example.com', 'East City', 3),
(4, 'Diana', 'Prince', 'diana.prince@example.com', 'Downtown', 1),
(5, 'Eve', 'Adams', 'eve.adams@example.com', 'East City', 3);

The jpqlWithObjectType has a count of 5 while jpqlWithLibraryType has a count of 3.
Why is this happening? I expect both queries to return the same number of rows since they are identical, but they are producing different results.
Additional Information:
There is a one-to-many relationship between Library and Member.
jpqlWithObjectType is using Object[] while jpqlWithLibraryType is using Library.class for the result type.
Could someone help explain why there is a difference in the number of results returned?
Since the queries are identical in structure (they both join the Library and Member entities on the library.id), I expected that they would return the same number of results.
In the database, I have 3 libraries and 5 members, and since each library has associated members, I anticipated that both queries would return 5 libraries, as the JOIN should match libraries with their respective members.
However, the results were:

The first query (Object[] result type) returned 5 rows.
The second query (Library result type) returned only 3 rows.


THis is what is called a carthesian product. You will get a row for every result in the query (that is with the Object[]). It iwll include some duplicated entries for the libraries as it will return a row for each member, including the library information. When returning a Library hibernate will flatten this into 3 dedicated library entities and assign the members to the correct Library.

To understand this, starting with the perhaps more intuitive second jpqlWithLibraryType query, we are seeing that a collection with 3 Library objects is returned.  This is expected, because there are only 3 Library objects/records available.
For the second jpqlWithObjectType case, the Object[] collection type will force Hibernate to map the raw/native result set directly.  This means that there will be two Object[] items in the list for library_id 1 and 3.  Each item will represent one of the two matching join conditions from the library to member tables.
Normally, you probably should not be using List<Object[]> when doing an HQL join.  Instead, use the second pattern and let Hibernate abstract away the raw result set into Java entity classes.

If you could point me to the relevant sections in the Hibernate User Guide, Jakarta Persistence Specification, or any other official resources that explain this behavior in detail, I would greatly appreciate it!

I don't have a reference (nor was I myself even aware of this prior to reading your question as I had never tried it).  But if you think about it, Hibernate needs some way of expressing the one-to-many relationship of libraries to members.  You can't express one-to-many using a single Object[] array.

I have that code in Library entity:
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "library", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List members;

Basically, you're telling Hibernate to take each record in the result set (and there are 5 of them), and stuff that into an Object[].  As mentioned, in the case of a join, this probably isn't what you want to be doing.

Which is to be expected and is called a cartesian product. This happens due to the JOIN. The JOIN will result in all rows from the Member table to be linked to a Library record. As there are 5 members you will get 5 rows, with some duplicate data for the Library information (id 1 and 3).
This is the same as would happen if you would execute the query as SQL (if it would have been written as SQL).
SELECT * FROM Library l
JOIN Member m ON m.library_id = l.id

This will JOIN both tables together and is also more or less the SQL query that Hibernate will execute (although instead of * it probably will list all columns it needs).
The raw SQL result is also what is being returned when you request an Object[], no flattening or marshalling into enity objects just the plain old SQL result.
Now if you ask Hibernate to convert the result into a Library (which is what you did with the second query due to the result type). Hibernate will iterate over the result set and for each unique library-id create a Library instance and cache it (the first level cache). For the columns of the Member table it will create a Member instance and add it to the Library that it just created (or from the cache if it already existed).
Now as there are only 3 Library records you end up with 3 instances of that entity, 2 of which have 2 members and 1 with only 1 member.
What you see here in effect is basically the whole premise of ORM, mapping objects to entity relationships (or more vice-versa here).
